# Send a POST request in R package

Tags: r, http, post, request

I've been trying to use httr package in R to send a POST request

The website which I'm trying to send a POST request states to do the following:

```
POST /newwebservices/locationverifier.asmx/findLocation2 HTTP/1.1
Host: citizenatlas.dc.gov
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: length
str=string&f=string
```

where **str** takes an address in Washington DC such as "701 FARADAY PL NE, WASHINGTON, DC 20017" and f takes the format requested in this case I want "json"

I tried :

```
url = "/newwebservices/locationverifier.asmx  HTTP/1.1"
body = list(
"Host" = "citizenatlas.dc.gov",
"Content-Type" = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
"Content-Length" =  length,
"str"="3513 S St NW",
"f"="json"
)
httr::POST(url,body, verbose)
```

I also tried Get
This is what they state to put in

```
GET /newwebservices/locationverifier.asmx/findLocation2?    str=string&f=string HTTP/1.1
Host: citizenatlas.dc.gov
```

or

```
   GET("http://citizenatlas.dc.gov/newwebservices/locationverifier.asmx/findLocation2?str=3513 S St NW&f=json")
```

but nothing is working.  By the way, I had no problem making the request using Mathematica.

I will appreciate any help.  Thank You in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few different things going on here. Below works:

```r
url <- "http://citizenatlas.dc.gov/newwebservices/locationverifier.asmx/findLocation2"
body <- list(str = "3513 S St NW", f = "json")
httr::POST(url, body = body, encode = "json")
```

A few differences:

- POST is to host + endpoint, not just endpoint
- Details on response (content type, length) are not included
- Encoding specified for body (per `httr::POST` documentation)
- `body` and `encode` are named because they aren't in positions from documentation, so positional argument matching won't work